# Access Database Server hosted in AWS private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

I have gone through AWS VPC(Virtual Private Cloud) where I can have public, Private and VPN-only Subnets.

With this, I want to host a Database in Private or VPN-only subnet.

Now that, Private and VPN-only subnet can not have Internet traffic, I wonder if I can access my database server from remote machine (not an EC2 instance nut any random machine on internet) ?

***So All I want to know that, how I can access my Database server from random machine using VPN connection ? So the only users those have VPN connections can access the database server***. I want this for development purpose.

Any comments links will be helpful.

Note: I am aware that I can do this with  VPN EC2 instance, but I don want to have one and directly connect to Database server from remote machine which has VPN connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you create a private VPC, all of the subnets you create within it have internal network access to each other by default in their route tables. However you would need to configure a NAT or Bastion instance within the VPC that *is* public to act as the gateway to the private database.

The private database would need to have an appropriate security group attached to it to allow it to be accessed by the public machine. See about [VPCs and Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html) here.